# PHP Mail never arrives

Tags: php, email, sender

Good Evening,

I'm trying to send an e-mail using php function mail

```
$to = $_POST['Mail'];
$subject = 'Test Mail';
$headers = 'Mime-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
$headers .= "\r\n";
$msg = 'Test Mail Sender';
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

But my probleme is that there is no error that pop's up when i execute this code but the message never arrives to the destination

Comment: will I get shot down for this too => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ? *sigh*

Comment: not enough info/code here.

Comment: `$headers .= "\r\n";` get rid of that for one thing.

Comment: Is your mail server configured?

Comment: i got sendmail.ini
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
default_domain=gmail.com
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=******@gmail.com
auth_password=*****@cec
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=******@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=

Comment: php.ini i got this
sendmail_path = "C:\Wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe"
smtp_port  = 25
SMTP = localhost